# Custom UILabel and its stroke

Tags: uilabel, stroke

I'm using a custom UILabel class with this drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, self.outlineSize);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
self.textColor = strokeColor;
[super drawTextInRect:rect];

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
self.textColor = fillColor;
self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

but I've a problem, when I change the strokeColor (myText.strokeColor = [self colorWithHex:0xe55f00]) through a pickerview it works correctly because it changes the color of the label's stroke.
Instead when I edit the fillColor it changes the color both the filling and the stroke!
(myText.fillColor = [self colorWithHex:0x000000])

What am I doing wrong??